# How can I free or delete system data on my Hard drive?

Tags: operating-system, storage, system

Why is System storage on my Mac so high? 
Can I delete System storage on my Mac?[System Data][1]

[Storage][2]

Cannot find or remove 70GB+ of "Hidden Space

image  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE4LF.png 
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P4NU.png 
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY91M.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try clearing system apps cache..
go through each system application and try clearing cache of each application
i've also gone with same problem system app clearing cache work for me try it once

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the same cause for everyone but i had a similar issue today, my system data section in the storage overview was well over 600gb of data. I used a db scanner to check and turns out it was just that I had docker running with that much available space.

So anyone running docker and noticing this issue might want to try reducing that.